# how to image display based on selection in android

Tags: android, android-imageview

please help me

how to image display based on selection in android

displaying images based on condition, condition is taken from xml parsing example if the weather is sunny then the picture changed

Comment: what do you use? an ImageView?

Comment: what is your condition and put some more relevant information for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an ImageView in your layout and set the image to whatever you want at runtime using the id of the imageview

Comment: Please be more specific about your peoblem